# How to add a custom new option in onkeyup event in jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Let I search **hello world** in a jquery autocomplete implemented textbox. My system has this keyword so autocomplete show this keyword as suggestion, but I want to add a new option **hello world**.

Please, see the picture bellow to understand what I want. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/01rbk4cx/

You can use `response` which is run after the search is finished and before the selection is shown; http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

Just use the callback and add your input's value to the search result:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
     source: availableTags,
     response: function(e, ui){
         ui.content.push({ label: $("#tags").val(), 
                           value: $("#tags").val()});
     }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Its works in demo. I will let you if I face any problem in my code.